# Does CUDA C++ math function of exp have override functions by default?

Tags: c++, cuda

The problem comes from the document where I find two function `exp` and `expf`. It is said that `exp` means `double exp(double)` and `expf` means `float expf(float)`. I wonder if `exp` can have default override version such as `float exp(float)` or `fp16 exp(fp16)`. Or must I use different functions when the input are different types ?

Consider a scenario where I use template:

```
template <typename T>
T compute (T in) {return exp(in);}
```

If there is no default `float exp(float)`, I cannot use `compute<float>(1.f)` to call this template function. I know that I can call that function like that but I do not how how does the compiler deal with it. When I call `exp(1.f)`, does the compiler first cast the input into `double` and the cast the return value back to `float`, or does the compiler use the float number as input directly?

Comment: @RobertCrovella So if I use `expf(double)`, the input will be casted into float and then the return will be casted back into double, which will bring some overhead on the performance. So I had better use `exp` for double and `expf` for float rather than use them crossingly, am I correct ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for replying !! If I use template to write the function, how could I let the compiler to choose the correct version according to the template type ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Unless something changed recently, CUDA uses the standard C++ overloading for standard math functions, and therefore `expf(float)` and `exp(float)` are functionally equivalent, i.e. both invoke the single-precision exponential function and identical SASS is generated. To invoke the double-precision exponential function, `exp(double)` is required.

Comment: @RobertCrovella See also CUDA 10.2 Programming Guide: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.2/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH.html

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for replying !!! Does `exp` also have a `exp(float16)` version or do I still need to call `hexp` instead ?

Comment: @CoinCheung No idea, the latest CUDA version I have used is 8, while the most recent one is 11. To my (limited) knowledge `float16` is *not* a standard type in C++17, so I am *guessing* there is no overload for this type for standard math functions. You could always check the header files to find out what overloads are in place.

Comment: I was in error, so I've removed most of my comments here.

Comment: @njuffa Hi, I have more question about this: I notice that not all math functions have associated fp16 version. For example, there is `hexp` which is for fp16, but there is no `hlog1p` which should be the fp16 version of `log1p` or `htan` which is fp16 version of `tan`. If I want my program work in fp16 mode, how should I compute these functions ?

Comment: @CoinCheung You can file enhancement requests with NVIDIA to suggest additional functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is said that exp means `double exp(double)` and `expf` means `float expf(float)`. I wonder if exp can have default override version such as `float exp(float)` ...

Yes, the CUDA compiler does what a normal C++ compiler does and will transparently overload the correct version of the function for the correct type. This works for `float`and `double` ...

> ... or `fp16 exp(fp16)`.

... but it does not presently work for half precision floating point.

As an example, this:

```
$ cat overlay.cu
#include <cuda_fp16.h>

template<typename T>
__global__ void kernel(const T* x, const T* y, T* output, int N)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N)
        output[tid] = exp(x[tid]) * y[tid];
};

template __global__ void kernel<float>(const float*, const float*, float*, int);
template __global__ void kernel<double>(const double*, const double*, double*, int);
```

will compile correctly:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_70 -Xptxas="-v" -c overlay.cu
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelIdEvPKT_S2_PS0_i' for 'sm_70'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6kernelIdEvPKT_S2_PS0_i
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 16 registers, 380 bytes cmem[0], 88 bytes cmem[2]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelIfEvPKT_S2_PS0_i' for 'sm_70'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6kernelIfEvPKT_S2_PS0_i
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 14 registers, 380 bytes cmem[0]
```

but adding

```
template __global__ void kernel<__half>(const __half*, const __half*, __half*, int);
```

will fail:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_70 -Xptxas="-v" -c overlay.cu
overlay.cu(9): error: more than one instance of overloaded function "exp" matches the argument list:
            function "std::exp(long double)"
            function "std::exp(float)"
            argument types are: (const __half)
          detected during instantiation of "void kernel(const T *, const T *, T *, int) [with T=__half]"
```

As pointed out in comments, C++14/C++17 don't define a standardized half precision type or standard library, so this error is pretty much in line with expected behaviour.

If you want a half precision version, then I suggest using explicit template specialization for the fp16 version which exploits the (most performant) intrinsic for the type, for example:

```
#include <cuda_fp16.h>

template<typename T>
__global__ void kernel(const T* x, const T* y, T* output, int N)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N)
        output[tid] = exp(x[tid]) * y[tid];
};

template __global__ void kernel<float>(const float*, const float*, float*, int);
template __global__ void kernel<double>(const double*, const double*, double*, int);

template<> __global__ void kernel(const __half* x, const __half* y, __half* output, int N)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N)
        output[tid] = hexp(x[tid]) * y[tid];
};
```

is probably the most optimal implementation at this stage, which compiles as expected:

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_70 -Xptxas="-v" -c overlay.cu
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelI6__halfEvPKT_S3_PS1_i' for 'sm_70'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6kernelI6__halfEvPKT_S3_PS1_i
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 12 registers, 380 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelIdEvPKT_S2_PS0_i' for 'sm_70'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6kernelIdEvPKT_S2_PS0_i
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 16 registers, 380 bytes cmem[0], 88 bytes cmem[2]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelIfEvPKT_S2_PS0_i' for 'sm_70'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6kernelIfEvPKT_S2_PS0_i
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 14 registers, 380 bytes cmem[0]
```

[Answer assembled from comments with own editorialisation added to get question off unanswered list for the CUDA tag. Please edit/improve as you see fit]

Comment: Does it means that when I implement my kernel functions with template feature, I should define an extra definition for `fp16` type such as `template<typename T> T fun(T a) {return exp(a);} template<> fp16 fun(fp16) {return static_cast<fp16>(exp(static_cast<float>(a));}` ?

Comment: No, don't do that. Make a separate specialization for the non-standard half precision case

Comment: Would you please write a little example to make it more clean what is the best way to handle this case?